# Возможно ли создать несколько перегрузок метода класса JS с разным числом параметров?

Tags: javascript, функции, function-overloading

Казалось бы, банальный вопрос, да вот столкнулся с тем, что не знаю, как выйти из такой ситуации: положим, есть у нас таковой "класс":

```
function TestClass() {
    this.method = function(index) {
        alert("index");
    };
    this.method = function(x, y) {
        alert("x, y");
    };
}
```

Поясню, что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
var test = new TestClass();
test.method(1); // Вылезает alert с текстом "index"
test.method(1, 1); // Вылезает alert с текстом "x, y"
```

То есть я пытаюсь сделать внутренний метод с несколькими вариантами перегрузок. Понятное дело, что приведенный выше синтаксис просто перезаписывает функцию, на которую ссылается сей вот импровизированный класс. Пробовал сделать так:

```
function TestClass() {
    function method(index) {
        alert("index");
    }
    function method(x, y) {
        alert("x, y");
    }
    this.method = method;
}
```

Однако же все равно для `TestClass().method(...)` используется последняя обозначенная перегрузка.
Возможно, вопрос уже задавали, однако сего я нагуглить не смог, так что прошу направить меня или поделиться знаниями, необходимыми для разрешения сего вопроса)

Comment: В js это так не работает, методы не различаются числом параметров и могут принимать любое количество аргументов, даже если некоторые их них небыли объявлены. Так что названия методов должны быть уникальны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Названия методов в js должны быть уникальны или же можно импровизировать перегрузку:

```js
let qwe=new class{
  method(...args){
    let overloads={
      1:()=>alert('Single argument: '+args[0]),
      2:()=>alert('Two arguments: '+args[0]+' and '+args[1])
    }[args.length]()
  }
}()
qwe.method('Celestia')
qwe.method('Celestia','Rarity')
```

Comment: И валится эксепшн, когда при вызове аргументов не 1 или не 2

Comment: @MikePapou так и задумано. У методов с перегрузкой есть строго установленное количество аргументов. Их может быть ни больше ни меньше, чем должно быть. Во всех остальных случаях - ексепшон. Можно было с ошибочкой оформить.

Answer (score 2):

Вам не надо делать перегрузки. Внутри любой функции в JS доступна переменная arguments, которая создержит array-like объект с переданными параметрами. То есть вы можете проверять arguments.length и обращаться к аргументам по индексу как в массиве.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function TestClass() {
}

TestClass.prototype.method = function(a, b) {
  if (b === undefined) {
    var i = a;
    console.log("index:", i);
  } else {
    var x = a, y = b;
    console.log("xy:", x, y);
  }
};

var test = new TestClass();
test.method(1);
test.method(1, 1);
```

Comment: Fuck the system: `test.method(1, undefined);`!

Comment: @Other, это нормально. Я мог бы `arguments.length === 1` проверить, но решил сделать единообразно с дефаултными параметрами (именно поэтому `=== undefined`, а не `== null`), которые уже есть в стандарте.

Comment: Но ведь считается именно количество переданных аргументов. А тут хоть передано 2, исполнился первый обработчик. Вдруг случайно поставят `undefined`?

Comment: @Other к слову, могут)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, в таком случае есть комментарий с заменой.