# Есть ли в php способ создать глобальную переменную? [Всё ещё актуален]

Tags: php

Я хочу сделать глобальную переменную, которую можно было бы использовать внутри функций. Но несколько часов экспериментов не дали мне результата.
Что я хочу:

```
$qwe='knot';
function(){
  echo $qwe;
}
```

При этом я не хочу использовать оператор `global` или получать доступ к переменной через суперглобальный массив`$GLOBALS`, ибо функций в коде у меня очень много и каждая из них требует глобальные переменные, да и просто это всё не эстетично и вызывает у меня кринж.

Я пробовал создать константу с `ArrayObject` внутри, чтобы по-минимуму отяготить код и получить такой синтаксис внутри функций:

```
define('q',new ArrayObject($_POST));
function(){
  echo q->qwe;
}
```

Хоть константа и доступна внутри функций, но в неё можно поместить только обычный массив, и, к тому же, нельзя присваивать ему новые свойства. Поэтому с этим вариантом невозможно работать.

Я также видел вариант установить дополнительное расширение для php, чтобы создавать свои суперглобальные переменные в `php.ini`. [Видел здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834491/create-superglobal-variables-in-php). Это был бы прекрасный вариант, если бы можно было делать тоже самое, но прямо в коде.

Есть ли на сегодняшний день какая бы то нибыло, даже самая мракобесная возможность создать глобальную переменную в PHP?

P.S. Статичного поле в классе ни в коем случае не походит на переменную и не подходит к решению вопроса.

P.S.S. Пожалуйста, не нужно убеждать меня перестроить архитектуру программы, я нуждаюсь в ответе на этот конкретный вопрос хотябы из позновательных соображений.

Я не могу помочь тем, кто не понимает вопроса. Как я могу исправить свой пост, чтобы эти люди стали сообразительнее? Мне нужна глобальная переменная - мне предлагают писать синглтоны или функции и удивляются, почему я не принимаю их ответы. НО Я ПРО СОЗДАНИЕ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ СПРАШИВАЛ! Мой вопрос не звучит как: "сто и один способ получить доступ к глобальной переменной из функции", но видимо для всех он именно таков. На самом деле мой вопрос очень интересен и действительно смекалистого на него решения не хватает всему PHP сообществу.

И видимо любая попытка в рассуждения и дискуссию около заданного вопроса приводят к замешательству и недопониманию. В следующий раз я буду просто минусовать и грубо отшивать всех, кто предлагает варианты не по теме.

Comment: Вас тогда спасет правильная архитектура приложения.

Comment: @Manitikyl Меня не надо спасать. Мне нужен способ создать глобальную переменную. В этом я уверен от гривы до кончика хвоста.

Comment: Используйте [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Comment: `Мне нужен способ создать глобальную переменную` - так используйте `$GLOBALS`. Это самый оптимальный вариант, но вы хотите костыли, хорошо...

Comment: Не хотите GLOBALS? Создайте синглтон MyGlobals и получайте MyGlobals::get('myGlobalVariable');

Comment: Я вас понял, Создайте статический класс, `StaticClass`, и создайте у него функцию `function get($var) { return $GLOBALS[$var]; }`, и тогда вы можете внутри своих функций вызывать не `$GLOBALS['qwe']`. P.S. манипуляции можно не поизводить в `$GLOBALS[$var]` а используя переменные.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov да, такой вариант я тоже рассматривал, если максимально сократить, то получится что-то вроде: `q::$q`, но этот вариант я бы стал использовать только от безысходности, ибо он тоже некрасивый.

Comment: @Diskyp тогда вариантов не осталось

Comment: @Manitikyl суть не в моей неприязни к слову GLOBALS, а к его длине и вообще этой возмутительной необходимостью использовать массив для доступа к глобальной переменной. Сменить его на функцию тоже самое, что сменить осла на мула - разница не велика, да ещё и накладывает свои ограничения.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov а и да, я вспомнил, что в статичную переменную я суперглобальный массив не помещу, а геттер/сеттер статичным сделать нельзя, и значит минимальный синтаксис этого варианта будет такой: q::q('q'), что, как можно заметить, ещё страшнее.

Comment: @Diskyp остался последний вариант. Объявляете свои переменные, ни в коем случае не пользуетесь классами и функциями, используете исключительно goto. Тогда вся программа будет в одной области видимости и все ваши переменные будут глобальны

Comment: "что в статичную переменную я суперглобальный массив не помещу" - можно использовать магические методы __get() и __set() для обращения к переменным, как к методам

Comment: @Diskyp вам надо менять язык программирования, я-то опубликовал все варианты, для тех кто понимает что он хочет, вы-же хотите магию, это в другую сторону.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov но гет/сет статичными не сделать, а значит у них та же проблема с видимостью. Вариант с goto конечно ахтунговый, я раньше вместо функций использовал switch, но теперь мне нужно все мои блоки кода поместить в массив и я теперь могу создавать только анонимные функции.

Comment: Похоже ТС просто решил потролить местное сообщество. Расходимся

Comment: @DmitryKozlov :D

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov какой унылый уровень троллинга у местного сообщества и какой я, оказывается, хитрый тролль, такие громоздкие шутки придумывать.

Comment: Автор сам не знает чего он хочет. Ему были предложены реальные решения с использованием паттернов (анти) проектирования.

Comment: достаточно фразы "я раньше вместо функций использовал switch"

Comment: @DmitryKozlov не я такой, среда разработки такая.

Comment: Ну всякое может быть. Переход от gw-basic сразу на пхп, например.

Comment: @ArchDemon добавил пояснение, почему я избегаю предложенных вариантов.

Comment: На ваш вопрос, при данной постановке, есть один ответ - "нет, такого способа в php не существует"

Comment: Попробуйте еще один антипаттерн extract($GLOBALS) в каждой своей функции

Answer (score 5):

**Вариант 1:**

http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.globals.php

```
function test(){
    echo $GLOBALS['qwe'];
}

$GLOBALS['qwe'] = 'knot';
test();
```

---

**Вариант 2**

```
class GlobalClass
{
    static $_stack = array();
    static function get($key) {
        return (isset(self::$_stack[$key])) ? self::$_stack[$key] : NULL;
    }

    static function add($key, $value = NULL) {
        self::$_stack[$key] = $value;
    }
}

function test(){
    echo GlobalClass::get('key1');
}
GlobalClass::add('key1', 'value1');
test();
```

---

**Вариант 3:**

```
class GlobalClass
{
    public $_stack = array();
    function get($key) {
        return (isset($this->_stack[$key])) ? $this->_stack[$key] : NULL;
    }

    function add($key, $value = NULL) {
        $this->_stack[$key] = $value;
    }
}

class NowClass extends GlobalClass {
    function __construct() {
        $this->add('key1', 'value1');
    }
    function test() {
        echo $this->get('key1');
    }
}

$class = new NowClass;
$class->test();
```

---

**Вариант 4:**

```
$global_stack = array();
function global_get($key)
{
    global $global_stack;
    return (isset($global_stack[$key])) ? $global_stack[$key] : NULL;
}
function global_add($key, $value = NULL)
{
    global $global_stack;
    $global_stack[$key] = $value;
}

class NowClass {
    function __construct() {
        global_add('key1', 'value1');
    }
    function test() {
        echo global_get('key1');
    }
}

$class = new NowClass;
$class->test();
```

Comment: Можете предоставить рабочий пример? Я там удовлетворяющего мой вопрос ответа не увидел.

Comment: Цитирую самого себя: При этом я не хочу использовать оператор `global` или получать доступ к переменной через суперглобальный массив `$GLOBALS`

Comment: Эти способы создают функции, как вы можете заметить из вопроса, я пытаюсь создать переменную.

Comment: @Diskyp вы что хотите? вы сами себе представляете? Вы хотите в одном месте создать `$a = 5;` и потом `$a` выводить везде где-только вздумается? Так не работает. По вашему вопросы видно что вы не против юзать `echo q->qwe;`, если вам нужна только одна букавка, то сделайте класс из одной букавки.

Comment: Всё не то, и покачто я остановился на собственном компиляторе дополнительного символа для глобальных переменных. Однако истина ещё не найдена.

Comment: @Manitikyl, интересно, почему вы все массивы называете стеками?

Comment: @vp_arth не все, тут бы я стек не использовал, но в других местах, обычно стек пишу в тех местах где переменная временная и должна быть уничтожена после того как она не нужна. Мне так легче понимать свой код :) где полезные переменные а где вспомогательные.

Comment: Вообще говоря, стек это в первую очередь LIFO.. Ну да ладно)

Comment: @vp_arth я знаю что такое стек, асм щупал. но картину не меняет

Comment: @vp_arth в след. раз когда увидите мой `stack` представляйте что это `temprorary` :D Ну вот так привык) сложилось так...

Answer (score -2):

```
/**
 * @property int $id
 */
class V {

   /**
    * @var V $ar
    */  
   public static $ar = [];

   private static $data = [];

   public function __get($name){
       return self::$data[$name];
   }

   public function __set($name, $value){
       self::$data[$name] = $value;
   }

   public function getAll(){
       return self::$data;
   } 

   /**
    * @return $this;
    */
   public static function init(){
       if(!self::$ar){
           self::$ar = new self();
       }

       return self::$ar;
   }
}

//Прежде чем использовать нужно инициализация класса
V::init();


V::$ar->id = 1;
print_r(V::$ar->getAll());
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ, могу согласиться, что это самый лучший рак на этом безрыбье, но всёравно это заставляет писать вдвое больше бессмысленного кода, нежели если бы была возможность просто создать глобальную переменную. Мне нужно прям какое-то изощрённое и революционное решение, может с изменением php.ini на лету или ещё что-то такое. Мои эксперименты пока продолжаются

Comment: В случае автокомплита со стороны IDE и предоставление возможных вариантов код может и получается длинее незначительно, но писать его оказывается быстрей и отлаживать проще. Вы попробуйте, вам понравится) А в имени глобальной переменной можно и ошибится, да и в случае нестандартного синтаксиса нет его подсветки и валидации. Я бы с ума сошел если б у меня код так выглядел
http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/07/24/0012/2001/813009/09/56c6a4eb7a.png

Comment: Хех, у меня проблем с валидацией точно не возникает, ибо её просто нет. Я слишком ленивый, даже чтобы создать фейковое подключение к серверам для активации лицензии вебшторма. В моём саблиме разницы вообще никакой, а знак `~` распознаётся как оператор http://prntscr.com/ka8hef. И чтобы выдать совсем уж убойный аргумент, я любитель хардкора и CSS синтаксиса и работаю с js фреймворком, который переделывает почти весь клиентский код в Emmet-подобный синтаксис. Меня дополнительными чёрточками точно не испугать.

Comment: @Diskyp Ну это хорошо что вы сами код пишете, а не дай бог какому-то бедолаге поддерживать ваш код, пока вы на Сейшелах загораете. Обновил ответ (если вы уже решили буквы экономить)

Comment: Ну уж нет, в мою империю идеального синтаксиса я подпускаю только избранных, и они по праву могут считать себя счастливцами. В моём мировоззрении пускай уж лучше весь мир читает мои доки и мануалы, нежели я буду тратить жизнь на чьи-то чужие, которые мне, к тому же, не нравятся.

Comment: P.S. А вообще для таких как вы в аду отдельный круг есть) Небось предпочитаете тернарные операторы вложенные, не ставите точку с запятой в JS там где и без нее работает да и вообще вас синтаксический сахар разбаловал)

Comment: О да, с вашей точки зрения я очень плохой жеребчик. Вот в этом ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848546/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-js-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5/848560#848560 пример моего js кода. Строгие языки не признаю.

Answer (score -2):

```
$tr = $_Post['responce'];
$GLOBALS['a'] = $tr;
```

Comment: Вообще никак не относится к теме вопроса, автор - как минимум невнимательный человек.

Answer (score -6):

За неимением лучшего варианта я решил пока создать свой небольшой компилятор дополнительного символа у переменных:

```
eval(preg_replace('/~\$([\w\d]+)/','$GLOBALS["$1"]','
~$globalVar="WoW!";
function qwe(){
    echo ~$globalVar;
}
qwe();
'));
```

Только вместо строки в `eval` - `file_get_contents` на вызываемый клиентом php файл.

**Синтаксис мой не трожьте! Это мой стиль и я хочу, чтобы весь код за моим авторством выглядел именно так.**

Comment: Если вам нужна именно глобальная переменная, может воспользоваться статическими свойствами класса? Имхо, этот вариант куда более грамотный, чем использовать ассоциативный массив, тк ближе ООП и учит хорошему стилю программирования, подобно java

Comment: @Александр С ООП я знаком уже давно, я даже написал свой полноценный фреймворк, правда на js для создания SPA приложух. Последний год я не учусь, а извращаюсь, чтобы сделать свой код максимально комфортным и эстетичным. Поэтому мне нужно именно то, что мне нужно.

Comment: eval... Ну если вас не волнует потеря производительности в два раза и потенциально уязвимая команда, то почему нет?

Comment: А что, если в коде точно не встретится такой же комбинации символов внутри текстовых строк или в виде включенного html кода и вы никогда в жизни не будете использовать побитовое НЕ (оператор `~`) то решение очень даже ничего. Особенно если при этом сделать систему сборки, которая будет эту замену выполнять не каждый раз при запуске файла, а в цикле разработки приложения, автоматически создавать итоговые .php на основе исходников. Или на худой конец для этих целей попробовать использовать auto_prepend_file. Хотя если вам мешают рамки такого скучного php, может сменить язык

Comment: @Mike кстати вообще не знал, что этот символ является оператором, сенкс за дополнительные пару битов полезной информации у меня в мозгу. Со строками конечно может получиться обосрамс, я думал об этом, но я эту систему сделал для серверного API, где строк почти нет, кроме эксепшонов. Но энивэй это пока просто костыль и я даже не отрицаю. Очень хотел перейти на ноду, но лень изучать его особенности, только ради того, чтобы написать одну АПИшку для моего js фреймворка. Потому мной было решено выжать всё из пыхпы.